# Computer stuck someone between QWERTY and Dvorak

Tags: windows, keyboard, dvorak

My Windows using friend tried to setup a Dvorak keyboard layout and something caused a reboot during the setup. Unfortunately his keyboard layout isn't quite QWERTY or Dvorak. I told him to type all the keys out and see what the new mapping is. Simple right? Wrong. He can't get past login and the only text field is the password field which obfuscates text entry. What should he do?

Comment: Start on-screen keyboard from assistive options on the login screen to get in

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - I think You can convert this to an answer.

Comment: @Divin3 OK, added as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the login screen there is the assistive tools option. From there you can open the on-screen keyboard with which you can log in.

The OSK also reflects the keymap currently selected so you can determine what is being used.

Also if there are several keymaps used pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> may switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

[Dvorak keyboard layout](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/KB_United_States_Dvorak.svg/900px-KB_United_States_Dvorak.svg.png)

Try to refer to this picture, I think it might be the keyboard layout the computer is on.

Comment: Unfortunately his keyboard layout isn't quite Dvorak, so showing him a Dvorak keyboard layout won't help him.